# Error Executing NPM command In VSTS CI Build

Tags: npm, webpack, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, npm-scripts

I'm new to CI Builds in VSTS and as a result, having a struggle with a specific npm task.

In the Build process, after the first five tasks execute, I use an npm task with a custom command. This command executes webpack script defined in my package.json

[image]

npm run prod

```
"prod": "webpack --env.NODE_ENV=production --config webpack.config.js --progress"
```

When this task runs, it errors with the following message

Error: Npm failed with return code: 1

Thoughts? Suggestions? This is trying me a little insane, I'm sure there's a simple solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `npm run prod` to `run prod` in command and arguments box.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the original error but now have a new one. I've updated the OP, pls have look when you get a chance, thanks!

Comment: Hey that fixed it, thanks. Much appreciated. The other error was b/c I had not set the path correctly for the package.json